# Editing Specific Raster Cells Via CSV Values using GDAL?

Tags: raster, gdal, csv

I have a raster grid that I would like to modify. I am trying to manually edit specific raster cells' values via vales in a CSV file.

My CSV contains three columns:

```
VAL,LAT,LON
91.0,31.04250,-86.31167
91.2,30.21889,-96.37417
75.9,41.00928,-74.73628
86.1,36.61056,-83.73722
89.0,34.28028,-87.60028
64.9,43.77714,-71.75598
68.0,44.42010,-72.01930
37.0,45.60444,-103.54639
68.0,39.16052,-89.67419
```

**Task Example**

[image]

In the above example, I would try to change the middle cell value from 65 to 67.

I would like to use `gdal` to accomplish this task.

Comment: What is the criteria for selecting the specific cells where the value will be changed?

Comment: The raster grid is set on lat/lon bounds. The values from the CSV are linked to a latitude/longitude point.